# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow in int

Tags: c#, visual-studio, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For getting the data of cloud firestore users/email/(key: values) with C#

I tried to pass using Email Text box i.e. TboxEmail.

```
DocumentReference docref = Data.Collection("users").Document(TboxEmail.Text);
DocumentSnapshot snap = await docref.GetSnapshotAsync();
```

I created a Userinfo class which gets all the data and selects only the required key: value.

```
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;

namespace FormApp
{
    [FirestoreData]
    class Userinfo
    {
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public bool status { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string address { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public int phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Code.

```
 bool s;
 try
 {
     DocumentReference docref = Data.Collection("users").Document(TboxEmail.Text);
     DocumentSnapshot snap = await docref.GetSnapshotAsync();

     if (snap.Exists)
                {
                    Userinfo userinfo = snap.ConvertTo<Userinfo>();
                    
                    s = userinfo.status;
                    if (s)
                    {
                            this.Hide();
                            Dashboard home = new Dashboard(TboxEmail.Text);
                            home.ShowDialog();
                            return;
                    }
                }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
            }
```

If i use a normal text like **test** in *(Firestore)/users(Collection)/text(Document)* and give the **test** in *TboxEmail* then, code runs **fine**.

---

Problem is when I use an **email** like **test@gmail.com**  in *(Firestore)/users(Collection)/email(Document)* and put **test@gmail.com**  in *TboxEmail* then the code above can't convert the data in *userinfo*.

Exception from *ex.Message* is

```
Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow
```

Exception from *ex.StackTrace* is

[image: ex.StackTrace]

Comment: "then the code above can't convert the data in userinfo" - if it doesn't throw an exception, then how is it failing? is it returning `userInfo == null` or is the `email` property `null` or an empty string `""` - or something else?

Comment: 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow' is the exception @Dai

Comment: Post the full details of that exceptioin, including the `Message` and `StackTrace` and do the same for every `InnerException`.

Comment: i'm new, i have posted my full code! @Dai could you help me?

Comment: Use your debugger to inspect `ex` inside the `catch` block.

Comment: ok here's an update! @Dai

Comment: Thank you @dai, Solved the issue by understanding the exceptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to guess the exact details but the exception hints at a problem with integers. Most phone numbers exceed the size of the `int` data type so I would look there. The solution would be to store phone numbers as string so that you can also represent country codes (such as +1) and not worry about integer precision.

Comment: Phone-numbers are strings, not integer-numbers anyway - as leading zeros are significant in many places, and you can't represent E.164 numbers correctly using integers either - nor extensions or alphanumeric numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Converting *int* into *Int64* for phone solves the issue!

```
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;
    
    namespace FormApp
{
    [FirestoreData]
    class Userinfo
    {
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string email { get; set; }
        .....
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public Int64 phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You still shouldn't be storing phone-numbers as integer values, you should be using a `string`. Phone numbers are not integers!